# Heroku: No Python Application Found for Flask App

Tags: python, flask, heroku

Heroku log is showing: **"--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---"**

My suspicion is the error within the module under *uwsgi.ini* file - I've tried multiple different permutations, but haven't been successful.

How can uwsgi.ini file be updated so that heroku can find the app?

Is the structure of my app not ideal for heroku deployment, if so how should I change the structure?

The Flask app has the structure below:

```
top_dir/
    instance/
        flask.cfg
    sub_dir/ 
        templates/
        tests/
        static/
        users/
            form.py
            views.py
        __init__.py
        models.py
run.py
Procfile
uwsgi.ini
requirements.txt
```

App starts with: *python run.py*

```
#run.py

from sub_dir import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

This is the code in *sub_dir/**init**.py*

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
app.config.from_pyfile('flask.cfg')
   #config file in top_dir/instance
```

Here is the code in the *uwsgi.ini* file

```
[uwsgi]
http-socket = :$(PORT)
master = true
die-on-term = true
module = sub_dir:run #error here?
memory-report = true
```

*Procfile*

```
web: uwsgi uwsgi.ini
```

Comment: Try changing the line:  
`from sub_dir import app` to `from sub_dir import app as application`

Comment: @RulerOfJustice, still getting the same error